# Why is it considered bad practice to use display:hidden for text in HTML?

Tags: html, css, image, hidden, indentation

I recently came across this tutorial that used a CSS background image to display a logo for a webpage instead of using an HTML  tag. There was a placeholder text inside the div containing the logo and in order to make that text disappear, the author used **text-indent:-9999px** instead of **display:hidden** because he said that it's bad practice to use the latter.

So, why is it considered bad practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because sometimes screen readers and search engines would ignore elements with `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` but not those positioned offscreen for the purposes of SEO and/or speech. However whether either method is 'bad practice' isn't really an industry-wide agreement, more of a preference thing depending on what the author really knows about these tools and what their objectives are for the site.

Also keep in mind that advice is at least 5 years old and that things change over time so what was 'best practice' then isn't automatically best practice now.

So, work out what YOU are trying to acheive and then consider your options and that is to my mind the 'best practice'.

Answer (score 2):

Primarily because screen readers will not read hidden content, but many will read content that has been positioned off-screen but is still visible.

Answer (score 2):

First of all there's nothing called `display: hidden;`, either its `display: none;` or it's `visibility: hidden;` or `overflow: hidden;` and coming to your question, I don't prefer using that, instead I use an `img` tag, with `alt` attribute which will describe my image, yes, screen readers DO READ `ALT` TEXT, if you don't have `alt` on your `img` tag, it will simply ignore it..

For example if am using `img` for my *logo* so I will use something like

```
<img src="#" alt="Company Name Logo" title="Company Name" />
```

Comment: Oh, my bad. I meant display:none. Thanks for your response! :)

Answer (score 2):

Using a background image for a logo means you can place logo text in the same element.

One reason for this is so accessibility readers (for the visually impaired) will read the logo text when the logo can't be seen. However, you do not want the text over the logo, so you text-indent to hide it.

Content in display:none elements are not read.

I am not 100% sure on this one, but I also remember reading that some search engines ignore content in hidden elements. They may however index indented content, but this needs verification.